# how to translate public event from c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, events, public

i have following code in a `c#` class and would need its vb.net equivalent. All online translation tools i found translate this part wrong. A research on the web did not bring me any progress.

```
    public event EventHandler<UploadProgressChangedLibArgs> UploadProgressChanged;
```

whatever I do I keep getting that uploadprogresschangedlibargs is not defined.

any help appreciated thanks

additional information:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetftplib/files/

this is the library i am trying to translate

Comment: Well *have* you declared `UploadProgressChangedLibArgs` anywhere? Where is it declared in the C# code?

Comment: I translated the Whole class from c# to vb.net online. but this part keeps failing. i didnt declare it anywhere, but it doesnt seem to be declared in the library itself too.

Comment: Well the type must be declared *somewhere*. Find out where in the C# code, and either add an appropriate reference to the right library, or add the declaration.

Comment: I've now looked at the library - it's just a separate class. You'll need to translate that into VB too. Why are you translating this code at all? You should be able to use the library from VB without translating it...

Comment: thank you! i would like to make some changes to the class and be able to debug it at runcode, thats why i am translating it to vb.net. i tried to add it as a c# code but it wouldnt see the class if i use mixed code.

Comment: No, a project has to be *either* completely C# *or* completely VB. You'd be better off learning enough C# to be able to make the change though, IMO. Part of the beauty of .NET is that you *can* call C# from VB and vice versa.

Comment: yes i am a beginner and thats why i am asking for help. your help has been very precious! if you'd post a resumee as answer i'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the compiler said: the `UploadProgressChangedLibArgs` type couldn't be found. That's another type within the same library - so you need to port *that* before you can port an event which uses it.

As noted in comments, I'd advise you to avoid porting C# to VB or vice versa unless you *really* need to. One of the benefits of .NET is that you can call C# from VB or vice versa - and if you just want to make minor changes to an existing code base, you don't need to port the whole thing - you just need to understand enough of the language it's written in to make that change.

Comment: if i get it right: it IS possible to have a c# class in a vb.net project.. right? what do you mean by "i can call c# from vb.net"? thanks

Comment: Not in the same project. You can reference a compiled assembly though.